# What to do when you bought in BTC and the product hasn't been delivered

Tags: ecommerce

I bought a supplement not available in my country (not drugs mind you) in bitcoin.

The company has given me all the proof that they had received my money but failed to send me my product and no longer answer my mails.

Is there any way I can get my bitcoins back ?

I tried to fill a claim but, for my country, bitcoins are not money - so the police told me that for them there is no transaction.

If not how can I help the bitcoin community by informing them to beware of this seller so they will not be stolen either (and for the FUD they are doing to the coin) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin is non refundable. What you can do is use sites such as Trustpilot to register your complaint. Also leave a review on Google.

Comment: Additionally, you may contact a lawyer/solicitor as you made a transfer of value and have suffered a loss.